# How to add jsf or html tags to p:panel 's header

Tags: jsf, primefaces, panel

```
 <p:panel id="sports" header="&lt;p:inputText id='headerz' value='text of headerz'" toggleable="true" closable="true" >
```

this is my code. Page doesnt show p:inputText. 
on the source code of page i can see the input text with id=headerz but it is greyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
<p:panel id="sports" toggleable="true" closable="true" >
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:inputText id='headerz' value='text of headerz' />
    </f:facet>  
</p:panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `header` attribute is meant for text **not for JSF markup**. In other words you may use it to give the panel a title, but not to add JSF components.